# load program/module at boot

Tags: linux, centos, boot, init-script, kernel-modules

I'm trying to load a program I wrote at boot. The program is also a module.ko and a small bash script. For the module I tried doing `depmod mymodule.ko` and `modprobe -a` and messing around with modprob libaries and .conf files without any success.

So, I wrapped it all (module and my executed program) in a bash script. I tried to load it at boot with rc.d. I failed this one too cause I think rc.d runs only executed files and not bash. If I'm right how do I change my bash file to an executed one? And install it in rc.d too? Is my strategy right?

Thank you all in advance :)

*working on Linux CentOS

Comment: There are parts of your question I don't understand. Your basic strategy is right, but obviously you didn't implement it correctly, and your description is too vague to understand what you did wrong. Try posting the *exact* commands you tried and any error message you got (use copy-paste).

Answer (score 1):

For your module, normally you'd normally put that in /etc/modprobe.conf but you can also put it in [/etc/rc.modules](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-kernel-modules-persistant.html).

For your script, if you want to just execute it once when the server boots, it can be put in [/etc/rc.d/rc.local](http://centos.org/docs/5/html/Installation_Guide-en-US/s1-boot-init-shutdown-run-boot.html) (although it is also executed when changing run levels). If you're looking for a more complex service you can start and stop or run at various run levels, you want a [System V Init script](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging%3aSysVInitScript)

Comment: thanks... first start with the module how do I do it exactly in modprobe.conf , I wortel "alias name mymodulename" whats the meaning of doing soo? where do I need toput my .ko file?